# Get all ul element which don't have specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have HTML like

```
<ul>
 <li>School
  <ul>
   <li> Tata
   <ul>
      <li>Foundation</li>
      <li> Engineering</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>College</li>
<li>Hospital</li>
<li> Truck
  <ul>
    <li>Tata</li>
   <li>Motor</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to use jquery to filter results on the basis of text e.g text="Tata" should show up the following result

```
<ul>
   <li> Tata
   <ul>
      <li>Foundation</li>
      <li> Engineering</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
<li>Tata</li>
```

Comment: You should format your code properly..

Comment: At least show us what you have tried. Please provide HTML/CSS and sample Js/JQ. **We're not a code writing service**

Answer (score 5):

Since what you really want is a "contains" search, I would use a filter with a regular expression search of the text.  Note this returns what you specified in the body of the question, but not the title. If you want the elements that don't match add a `!` to the condition being returned.  Note also, this is a case insensitive search.

**EDIT** Updated to narrow it down to only the inner most `li` containing the text.

```
var $matches = $('li').filter(function() {
    return findMatches(this,'Tata') && !findMatches($(this).children(),'Tata');
});

function findMatches(elem, str) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, 'i');
    return regex.test($(elem).text());
}
```

Using `:contains("Tata")` might be more appropriate if you care about case.

```
var $othermatches = $('li:contains("Tata")').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).children(':contains("Tata")').length;
});
```

Working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/vnwQ3/

Comment: First solution using `match` seems to result in an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` [http://jsfiddle.net/uFeL8/](). Second solution using contains causes incorrect results to be returned [http://jsfiddle.net/kA8kD/](http://jsfiddle.net/kA8kD/) `<-- See element [0] in result`.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - fixed - didn't notice that it wasn't suppose to include the outer `li`  Not sure exactly how to reproduce his results exactly as they aren't consistent.

Comment: +1 for working examples and working out how to not include the children. I didn't see your update until just now as was trying to work out my own answer. I like the shortness of `!$(this).children(':contains("Tata")').length`. Looks much nicer then my `clone().children()/remove().end().text()` solution......and **yes** OP's posted expectations are not consistent. The only thing in the back of my mind now is a `jsPerf` but that is not something for this post. Nice answer, nice code :)

Comment: +1 just to let you know that you missed to get the parent for the first `li` element in `$othermatches`..  but still it is a nice code :)

Comment: @Praveen - yeah, it's inconsistent. I choose to just pull the `li` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try with `:contains('text')` in jQuery like

```
$("li:contains('Tata')").parent();  // returns ul
```

---

**Updates:**

After looking properly into the html given by OP,

Using `:contains('text')`with some conditional logic will render the result as OP expected.

```
$('li:contains("Tata")').each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf("Tata") === 0) { //look for first occurrence
        if ($(this).children().length === 0) { //check the length to see individual lis
            console.log(this); 
        } else {
            console.log($(this).parent()[0]); //if it has children get its parent
        }
    }
});
```

> **Result:**   (1st console)
>
> ```
> <ul>
>    <li> Tata
>    <ul>
>       <li>Foundation</li>
>       <li> Engineering</li>
>    </ul>
>   </li>
>   </ul>
> ```
>
> (2nd console)
>
> ```
> <li>Tata</li>
> ```

This is purely based on the result that OP wants.  But I doubt that this is not indented for project might be a challenge quest(if any)

However I like the [elegance](http://jsfiddle.net/vnwQ3/) of @tvanfosson but he missed to check the 1st result's parent.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/A25Ez/1/)**

Comment: This answer yields incorrect results. Problem with using `contains` is that it will always inspects all levels into the child node tree and not just inspects the text of the current node. Hence you get incorrect results and also get the most outer `UL` always returned too. See [http://jsfiddle.net/kA8kD/](http://jsfiddle.net/kA8kD/) and check the first result `[0]`

Comment: @François You could adjust the selector accordingly to prevent that

Comment: @Christoph: then the answer should do that to make the answer correct :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl actually `:contains()` is the good place to start and what happens the code of OP's bit confused like `ul in li and it has ul..`  Now I have corrected with basic conditional statements, have a look at it :).

Comment: @Praveen: Nice update. Now the code takes expectations into account, even more so than the results the other answers provided. Though, OPs expectation looks strange in the first place. I think if one's use case requires to retrieve inconsistent results from identical matches where for some results you need the parent and for others you not, then either that use case is compensating for a bad implementation, OP has not explained it well and left important information out or OP simply copy-pasted original HTML without fixing it fully up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$('li').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == "your specified text"){
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id');//ul ids are alerted
  }
})
```

Comment: this won't work. A single newline will cause this to break.

Comment: Please try your solution in a fiddle before posting the answers and check your results with OP's expected results!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **filter**

```
$(function(){
   var filtered =  $('li').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() == 'Tata';
    });

    console.log(filtered)
})
```

Comment: better use match instead of an equal operator which is susceptible to whitespaces.

Comment: This answer only finds the exact text match `<li>Tara</li>` but does not match `<li> Tata<ul><li>Foundation</li><li> Engineering</li></ul></li>` as expected by OP.